# iOS Custom buttons not showing for interactive notification

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

I am currently working on interactive iOS notifications made ​​by 8 and honestly, I really struggle to see my buttons.
With the code below, I fail to see my buttons:

//INTERACIVE

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction =
[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

acceptAction.identifier = @"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER";
acceptAction.title = @"Accept";
acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
acceptAction.destructive = NO;
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *maybeAction =
[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

maybeAction.identifier = @"MAYBE_IDENTIFIER";
maybeAction.title = @"Maybe";
maybeAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
maybeAction.destructive = NO;
maybeAction.authenticationRequired = YES;


UIMutableUserNotificationAction *declineAction =
[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

declineAction.identifier = @"DECLINE_IDENTIFIER";
declineAction.title = @"Decline";
declineAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
declineAction.destructive = YES;
declineAction.authenticationRequired = NO;


UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *inviteCategory =
[[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];

inviteCategory.identifier = @"INVITE_CATEGORY";

[inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction, maybeAction, declineAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

[inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction, declineAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];


NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:inviteCategory, nil];
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Testing";
localNotification.category = @"INVITE_CATEGORY"; //  Same as category identifier
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Any Idea for my problem?
Despite all the examples on the Internet, I'm apparently the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a really great tutorial here: [The Code Ninja](http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/90742435155/notifications-in-ios-8-part-2-using-swift-what-is)

Everything in your code looks fine.  I've gotta ask to make sure you're not just overlooking what actually happens - if you were looking at the notification on the home screen, did you swipe left on the notification to reveal the buttons?

Here is what I am using (sorry about the swift)

**Initial Prompt for notifications**

```
    var openAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    openAction.identifier = "OPEN_IDENTIFIER"
    openAction.title = "Open"
    openAction.destructive = false
    openAction.authenticationRequired = false
    openAction.activationMode = .Foreground

    var snoozeAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    snoozeAction.identifier = "SNOOZE_IDENTIFIER"
    snoozeAction.title = "Snooze"
    snoozeAction.destructive = true
    snoozeAction.authenticationRequired = false
    snoozeAction.activationMode = .Background

    var snoozeable = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    snoozeable.identifier = NOTE_SNOOZE_CAT
    snoozeable.setActions([openAction, snoozeAction], forContext: .Default)
    snoozeable.setActions([openAction, snoozeAction], forContext: .Default)

    var notSnoozable = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    notSnoozable.identifier = NOTE_NO_SNOOZE_CAT
    notSnoozable.setActions([openAction], forContext: .Default)
    notSnoozable.setActions([openAction], forContext: .Default)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert |
        .Badge, categories: NSSet(array:[snoozeable, notSnoozable])
        ))
```

**Local Notification**

```
    var notification             = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate        = fireDate
    notification.timeZone        = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notification.alertBody       = "Alert Body"
    notification.userInfo        = userInfo
    notification.category        = blnCanSnooze ? NOTE_SNOOZE_CAT : NOTE_NO_SNOOZE_CAT
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: I think in the second `snoozeable.setActions([openAction, snoozeAction], forContext: .Default)`, you meant to replace `.Default` with `.Minimal`. Same for `notSnoozable`.

Comment: @Stephen: Do you know how Reminders app decides about whether to use category of actions with 'Minimal' context or with 'Default' context?

Comment: @Chanchal - The notification type depends on which notification is being displayed.  The Default reminder is what appears on the home screen(I think it supports 4 actions).  The minimal context is used when the notification comes from the notification banner (dropdown at the top/modal popup notification) which only supports 2 actions.

Comment: @StephenDonnell, You are right about both. I was wondering how Reminder app happen to use the 'Default' context by default (when u install iOS), but we can't set the 'Default' option for our app by default. It is the user who will choose whether the notifications, for an app, should appear as an Alert or as banner. We can't force it. Banners are the default way that apple chooses for our apps.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different issue. I was dealing with multiple types of notifications. **Few of my notifications were not showing action buttons while few were**. Found out that only the notification which was set at last was showing action buttons. I was stupid not to think that identifier of category is overridden with the last set notification as the settings are shared.
For dealing with this, we need to extract the current notification settings, add ours to it and set it back again:

```
    NSMutableArray *arrNewCategories = [NSMutableArray new];
    UIUserNotificationSettings *oldSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]currentUserNotificationSettings];
    for (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *oldCategory in oldSettings.categories)
    {
      if (![oldCategory.identifier isEqualToString:newNotificationCategory.identifier])
           [arrNewCategories addObject:oldCategory];
    }
    [arrNewCategories addObject:newNotificationCategory];

    UIUserNotificationType notificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *newSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationType categories:[NSSet setWithArray:arrNewCategories]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:newSettings];
```

Just make sure that the identifier of newNotificationCategory matches with your UILocalNotification's category.

Comment: I am getting this same issue with my local notifications, where should i put this code and what is oldCategory, newNotificationCategory?

Comment: Wherever you are creating a notification you should follow this. For adding each notification you also need to add a UIMutableUserNotificationCategory with it, here for my new notification it is newNotificationCategory with new settings, oldCategory object in the loop will contain the category for all previous notification which you have already added.